# Symfony2 -> Render Default format (e.g. html) if the one requested (e.g. mobile) doesn't exist

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In Symfony2, when trying to render `index.mobile.twig`, **How would I load `index.html.twig` when `index.mobile.twig` doesn't exist.** instead go getting a "this template does not exist error".

I believe the answer lies somewhere with creating a custom loader for Twig but I couldn't find any documentation on it, just occasional references to it.

Comment: Use [LiipThemeBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer involves extending the `twig.loader.class` and creating an additional step once it's discovered that the specific twig template doesn't exist and before the Exception is thrown.

**PART 1 - Configuration**

The answer involves extending the `twig.loader.class`.

1. Create a `customloader.php` which extends the Twig `FilesystemLoader` file.

   ```
   namespace Acme\MyBundle\Twig\Loader;       
   use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Loader\FilesystemLoader;
   class CustomLoader extends FilesystemLoader{}
   ```
2. Modify your `config.yml` to include:

```
 parameters: 
     twig.loader.class: Acme\YourBundle\Twig\Loader\name_of_your_class
```

---

**PART 2 - Extending the class**

Extending the class is fairly straight forward.. The method I needed to modify was `findTemplate($template)`. It's very small method and you could probably use `parent::` to extend the original code more properly.. However, I chose to completely over-write it and include the following code right before the `Unable to find template` error:

```
    if (false === $file || null === $file) {

        switch( $template->get('format')){
            case 'mobile':
                    $template->set('format','html');
                    return self::findTemplate($template->getLogicalName());
                break;
        }

        throw new \Twig_Error_Loader(sprintf('Unable to find template "%s".', $logicalName), -1, null, $previous);
```

After the code realizes that the file exists, it checks to see if `mobile` was the requested format. IF it is, it sets the format of the template object to `html` and then tries the `name.html.twig`. There's a lot more you could do in this area but this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to catch the Exception that is thrown by twig and retry it in the catch scope with the other template.

twig will throw a InvalidArgumentException when the template doesnt exist, but i am not sure if this isnt also thrown with other errors.

But anyway, try something like:

```
try {
    $template = $this->render('index.mobile.twig');
} catch (\InvalidArgumentException $exc) {
    $template = $this->render('index.html.twig');
}
return $template;
```

Comment: I think the answer lies in extending the `Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine::load` .. and that's where you see a try catch (similar to what you mentioned) I think modifying that method would solve my problem.. but I haven't figured out how to extend that class yet.  If you can, take a look at that file.. Any ideas?

Comment: im not really sure, but you can try to override the parameter templating.engine.twig.class with your class. i would prefer not to mess with such core things but rather make a custom render method in some basic controller from which other controllers inherit. there you can handle the catch switch.

Comment: I've tried to override the parameter `templating.engine.twig.class` .. I did it in my config.yml [ engine: 'extension.of.twigengine.service' ] .. This created and error for me, but attempts outside that didn't register any changes.

Comment: the parameter comes from here: /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/config/twig.xml. maybe this helps. Did you override like this: `parameters: templating.engine.twig.class: myClass` (with correct linebreaks)

Comment: yes, ivobo - I've overwritten that parameter.. Nothing seems to happen.. It seems like the class is hardcoded in the twig.xml. I can't figure out why is doesn't over ride it.

Comment: as seen here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682796/how-to-change-twig-loader-via-symfony2-settings, you might have to add it under services and not under parameters