# Add new Twig Loader at the top of the Twig Loader chain

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to create a new `TwigLoader` class and have it trigger before Symfony's `TwigLoader` class.

This [Stackoverflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343435/how-to-register-another-custom-twig-loader-in-symfony2-environment) was helpful however I cannot define a weight therefore my custom loader triggers only if Symfony's loader doesn't find the template.

I want that logic to be contained within my bundle so I **don't** want to:

- define my custom `TwigLoader` in `app/config.yml`
- override Symfony's `TwigLoader`

Currently, the Symfony Twig loader either fall back on the default Twig loading mechanism or if the path is something like `@Bundle:Controller:Action.format.engine` will try to load the file `@Bundle/Resources/views/Controller/Action.html.twig`.

In my case, I want to be able to map `@Bundle:Controller:Action.format.engine` to a completely different path and if that path doesn't match an existing file then it should fall back on the default behavior (Symfony's Twig Loader).

There are probably other ways to tackle the problem but it seemed to be the most appropriate way to accomplish the task.

I am building a BaseThemeBundle which I'll use on my open source forum project and I want to be able to easily isolate themes from bundles and potentially do all kind of cool stuff. :)

So far I've created a custom Twig loader that looks like [Symfony's Twig loader](https://github.com/teapotio/BaseThemeBundle/blob/fc729ea922e4f1453755df0483a49d26afccfed6/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php). And I've created a [custom Template locator](https://github.com/teapotio/BaseThemeBundle/blob/fc729ea922e4f1453755df0483a49d26afccfed6/Loader/TemplateLocator.php).

Any ideas, solutions or improvements?

Comment: would it be useful to everyone to appreciate what problem you are trying to solve by using such a loader? Maybe you would add the 'use case' to your question?

Comment: very true, I've added context to my question

Answer (score 0):

For this to work with all the templating engines, i think you should create a new Template Locator (maybe extending Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Loader\TemplateLocator) and overwrite in the DI container the default one by setting the alias "templating.locator" to your newly created Template Locator.

To make your template locator class to look first in the folders you want, you have to create a file locator (Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocatorInterface) for the new paths and inject it into your Template Locator class.